Is there a root function in python?
I want a thing that you can import two numbers and it will calculate the root of the number.
like I put (4, 2) and it output 2 or (27, 3) or ant combination.
I already tried: math.sqrt, but this is only for square root.

Roots are just the reciprocal of powers, so if you need an nth root of some number you just raise that number to the power 1/n and done.

For example, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow

root(4, 2) and root(27, 3) are the same as pow(4, 1/2) and pow(27, 1/3) https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow

"import" is a typo of "input", right? Please [edit] to fix it.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Related: How do I calculate square root in Python? This is a canonical question I wrote that mentions a bunch of related questions including some about nth roots.

Mathematically, n-th root of x is equivalent to x to the power of 1/n. So:
def nth_root(x, n):
    return x ** (1 / n)

print(nth_root(4, 2))
# => 2.0

print(nth_root(27, 3))
# => 3.0


Although this needs a little "sign hackery" if you need odd roots for negative numbers (e.g. the cube root of -27 is the perfectly well-defined real value -3, but it does not have a real square root, so you need to check both the input value and the root to see if you need to do more work).
